# Need help listing AD Properties and Filters

Tags: powershell

I am very new to powershell and my company wants me to find out a bunch of stuff about the Computers we use  in our AD DS ->

```
      (Name, Manufacturer, PC-Model, Serial number, WinVer)
```

(e.g -> MS002, Lenovo, M600, PF6KSY, Windows 10 Version 21H2)

I currently have this Script:

***Get-ADComputer -Filter { Name -like 'MS*' } -Propert LastLogonTimestamp |
Select Name, LastLogonTimestamp | Format-Table -AutoSize***

It shows me the AD Computers with the Correct name but i dont know how to add other parameters to the command, so it also displays serialnumber etc. I couldnt really find any solution to this while browsing the internet.

I would be super thankful if someone can help me on this!

Answer (score 0):

You specify which properties you want to return in the parameters for `Get-ADComputer`, and can retrieve more by comma separating the values

**Example**

`Get-ADComputer -Filter { Name -like 'MS' } -Properties Name, LastLogonTimestamp, OperatingSystem, OperatingSystemVersion`

Or you can return all properties with the `*` character

`Get-ADComputer -Filter { Name -like 'MS' } -Properties *`

However, the properties you're requesting such as Manufacturer, Model, SerialNumber, etc., are not stored in AD

Comment: Hello Scott :)
Thank you for the help! So it is not possible to display all the Information i am looking for in one Script, since some values are located in the AD and others arent (like Serialnumber etc.)?

Comment: It's still possible to do in 1 script, you would just need to retrieve some info from another source, such as SCCM